# How to calculate the shipping cost based on distance

Tags: c

I wrote the following code which takes 2 inputs from user

1. weight of package
2. miles

I'm having trouble with the miles part.

This is part of my homework which asks to write a code that outputs the following (regarding the miles):

> The program calculates the cost to ship based on distance.it cost
>   $6.66 for each 250 miles or part thereof. For example, if the distance
>   is 251 miles then the cost based on distance is $13.32. I need help
>   with this part.

This is the code I wrote so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    //*** Naming of variables
    float weight;
    int distance;
    float costpackageweight;
    float costdistancetoship;
    //*** asking user for first input of the number of miles to ship a package
    printf(" Please enter the number of miles to ship the package \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &distance);

    //*** asking user for 2nd input of the weight of the package to ship
    printf(" Please enter the weight of the package to ship \n");
    scanf_s("%f", &weight);


    printf(" Package weight is %.2lf pounds. \n", weight);


    printf(" Distance to ship is %d miles. \n", distance);


    if (weight <= 10) {
        printf(" Cost to ship based on weight is..: $10.00 \n");
    }
    else if (weight > 10) {
        costpackageweight = (weight - 10) * 1.55f;
        printf(" Cost to ship based on weight is..: $%.2lf \n", costpackageweight);
    }

    if (distance < 250) {
        printf(" Cost to ship based on distance is: $6.66 \n");
    }
    else if (distance > 250) {
        costdistancetoship = (distance % 250)*6.66f;
        printf(" Cost to ship based on distance is: %.2lf \n", costdistancetoship);
    }
}
```

Comment: That calculation also same as this `costpackageweight = (weight - 10) * 1.55;`.

Comment: @Kalana I don't think so. I think that for every 250 or part of it you add 6.66 to the cost. So it is different from the weight case.

Comment: @DavidS yes, I understand that question in wrong way. sorry for that

Comment: `cost += (miles + 249) / 250 * 6.66; /* cost based on miles is this */`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following in order to find the multipler needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
//*** Naming of variables
float weight;
int distance, distanceMul;
float costpackageweight;
float costdistancetoship;
//*** asking user for first input of the number of miles to ship a package
printf(" Please enter the number of miles to ship the package \n");
scanf("%d", &distance);

//*** asking user for 2nd input of the weight of the package to ship
printf(" Please enter the weight of the package to ship \n");
scanf("%f", &weight);


printf(" Package weight is %.2lf pounds. \n", weight);


printf(" Distance to ship is %d miles. \n", distance);


if (weight <= 10) {
    printf(" Cost to ship based on weight is..: $10.00 \n");
}
else if (weight > 10) {
    costpackageweight = (weight - 10) * 1.55f;
    printf(" Cost to ship based on weight is..: $%.2lf \n", costpackageweight);
}

distanceMul = (distance + 249) / 250;
printf("%d\n", distanceMul);
costdistancetoship = distanceMul * 6.66f;
printf(" Cost to ship based on distance is:%.2lf \n", costdistancetoship);

}
```

Without using the if-else it is unnecessary.

*The logic is:*

When you divide the `distance` by 250, it will be casted to int type no matter the result, but because you need to start from 1 you add 1. Once calculated the desired multiplier you should just multiply it by the cost to get the desired result no matter what is the distance.

- 250 miles -> 1 * 6.66
- 251 miles -> 2 * 6.66
- 503 miles -> 3 * 6.66

Comment: In your case, you would pay double for your very first example. You need to *add* (250 - 1) and *then* divide by 250.

Comment: @Cheatah You are correct, I didn't validated that option. Edited the answer. Basically there is also a need to validate the distance entered by the user.

Comment: Your code fails for distance = 0.  It underflows to -1 * 6.66.  You should use `cost += (miles + 249) / 250 * 6.66;`

Comment: @LuisColorado Thanks for enlighten me. I should have done more validation tests.

Comment: Don't worry, the thing is that I'm 57 and have been writing C code for more than 40 years now.  But you're welcome anyway! :)